# what's does rethrow do in dart, and how it differ than throw

Tags: flutter, dart

I know what does `throw` keyword dp in a dart / flutter code, but I don't seem to understand the `rethrow`

I see it in examples like :

```
void misbehave() {
  try {
   // code
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow; 
  }
}
```

what does exacltly `rethrow`  do in that code, I don't seem to understand the concept behind it from the dart documentation.

any informations will be pricefull

I want to know what `rethrow` does in my code

Comment: actually, I searched and saw that question,  but I just didn't get it, when should I use the throw and rethrow

Comment: As stated in that answer: `rethrow` preserves the original stack trace.  This matters if you're debugging: if the exception goes uncaught and crashes your app, what do you want the stacktrace to blame?  The function that originally threw the exception or the function that caught and threw it again?

Answer (score 0):

In simple words

The throw is used to throw a new exception.

rethrow throws the expectation that it received from the other function call function.

**Example**

Suppose use have this function

```
void divideByZero(){
      try{
          0/0
} catch (error){

//You will receive the exception here.
//You can perform some operations here or throw the exception if the operations defined here can not handle that exception. 
// But it won't preserve the stack trace of the original exception.

//It's better to use rethrow if you have this kind of case.

}
}
```